# how to reliably detect shaking on all android device variations?

Tags: android, ios, accelerometer, gesture, shake

I have an app that detects shake gestures using https://github.com/square/seismic. However, it seems that on certain devices, this just doesn't work very well. For some users, their gyro might just be busted, but for others, setting even the minimum sensitivity still doesn't work. Sometimes on Android N devices, it looks like the shake gesture is hit every 200ms or so. When they restart, the problem goes away.

on some devices like the samsung galaxy s6, the gesture detection works perfectly each time.

on some edge devices, the shake gestures are not being recognized at all.

Outside of asking a user to calibrate their device, is there a more reliable way to detect shake gesture on Android devices? Apple provides this for free for iOS.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?